# is $E(x),E(y) ↦ E(x+y)$ well defined?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $x,y\in \mathbb R$ and $x\sim y \iff x-y\in \mathbb Z$. $E(x)$ is
>   the equivalance class containing $x$.

a) Is $E((x),E(y)) ↦ E({x+y})$ well defined?
Where $\rightarrow$ means an operation

b) Is $(E(x),E(y)) ↦ E(xy)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $(E(x),E(y))=E(x+y)$ (the first part of what you say you thought for part (a))?  It says that a certain pair of equivalence classes *equals* a single equivalence class, and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: The part of the question you quoted does not say or ask $(E(x),E(y))=E(x+y)$; the closest it comes to that is $(E(x),E(y))\mapsto E(x+y)$, which does make sense.

Comment: And does it mean $(E(x),E(y))=E(x+y)$? The definition says that $g : (X/∼) → Z$ is well-defined if I there exists a mapping $f : X → Z$
such that$ f$ has the property $x \sim y → f(x) = f(y)$ and$ g = f$

Comment: No, it does not mean that equation (or any equation). It is a name for a function, namely the function that maps each pair $(E(x),E(y))$ of equivalence classes to the equivalence class $E(x+y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is well defined.  Here is the proof.

Fix some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, and choose some $x'\in E(x)$ and $y'\in E(y)$.  It suffices to show that $E(x+y)=E(x'+y')$.

This is easy to see, as

$$(x'+y')-(x+y)=(x'-x)+(y'-y)=\text{integer}+\text{integer}=\text{integer}.$$

Now consider the case of multiplication.  We would **want to show** that $E(xy)=E(x'y')$.  However this is not always the case.  Observe that

$$x'y'-xy=(x'y'-x'y)+(x'y-xy)=x'(y'-y)+y(x'-x)=x'\cdot\text{integer}+y\cdot\text{integer}.$$

We need only choose any example in which the latter formula is not an integer.  Take for example

$x=0$

$x'=1$

$y=\pi$

$y'=\pi+1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, cleared everything up. The last part is false by couterexample.

Comment: @GRS, No problem, and I added one.

Answer (score 1):

If the notation $(E(x),E(y))$ is mean an operation, then $(E(x),E(y))=(E(z),E(w))$.
If the notation $(E(x),E(y))$ is mean an pair, then $(E(x),E(y))\neq(E(z),E(w))$.